# User ldap cannot change password : LDAP password information update failed: Insufficient access

Tags: linux, centos, ldap, openldap

I'm using centos 6.7 to create LDAP server, but the user still cannot change their own password.

The error when user try to change the password :

```
[john2@servergw ~]$ passwd
Changing password for user john2.
Enter login(LDAP) password: 
New password: 
Retype new password: 
LDAP password information update failed: Insufficient access
Retype new password:
```

here is my /etc/openldap/slapd.conf on server-side :

```
access to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange
  by self write
  by anonymous auth
  by * none
access to *
  by self write
  by * read
```

My /etc/pam.d/passwd on client-side :

```
password required pam_cracklib.so retry=3
password sufficient pam_ldap.so use_authtok
password sufficient pam_unix.so nullok use_authtok md5 shadow
password required pam_deny.so
#%PAM-1.0
auth       include      system-auth
account    include      system-auth
password   substack     system-auth
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

try using this ACL in your olcDatabase={2}bdb.ldif file

```
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword by self write by dn.base="cn=admin,dc=domain,dc=com" write by anonymous auth by * none
```

Using the dn.base allow him to write the password. Some suggest to create a user that his sole role is to do such a thing, but i found using the dn.base usually works well

Comment: Doesn't this allow anyone to change anyone else's password?